# Navigation pop view when swipe right like Instagram iPhone app.How i achieve this?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I want to pop a view when swipe right on screen or it's work like back button of navigation bar.

I am using:

```
self.navigationController.interactivePopGestureRecognizer.delegate = (id<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>)self;
```

This single line of code for pop navigation view and it's a work for me but when i swipe form middle of screen this will not work like Instagram iPhone app.

Here i give a one screen of Instagram app in that you can see the Example of swipe right pop navigation view:

[image]

Comment: You should follow this question (it doesn't have answers yet, but it is a duplicate) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714595/extend-default-interactivepopgesturerecognizer-beyond-screen-edge

Comment: The perfect solution with code and explanation:- http://stackoverflow.com/a/32990248/988169

Comment: Check these repos: https://github.com/rishi420/SwipeRightToPopController/blob/master/SwipeRightToPopController/SwipeRightToPopViewController.swift and https://github.com/fastred/SloppySwiper/blob/master/Classes/SSWDirectionalPanGestureRecognizer.m

Answer (score 14):

Apple's automatic implementation of the "swipe right to pop VC" only works for the left ~20 points of the screen. This way, they make sure they don't mess with your app's functionalities. Imagine you have a `UIScrollView` on screen, and you can't swipe right because it keeps poping VCs out. This wouldn't be nice.

Apple says [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/interactivePopGestureRecognizer) :

> **interactivePopGestureRecognizer**
>
> The gesture recognizer responsible for popping the top view controller off the navigation stack. (read-only)
>
> @property(nonatomic, readonly) UIGestureRecognizer *interactivePopGestureRecognizer
>
> The navigation controller installs this gesture recognizer on its view
>   and uses it to pop the topmost view controller off the navigation
>   stack. You can use this property to retrieve the gesture recognizer
>   and tie it to the behavior of other gesture recognizers in your user
>   interface. When tying your gesture recognizers together, make sure
>   they recognize their gestures simultaneously to ensure that your
>   gesture recognizers are given a chance to handle the event.

So you will have to implement your own `UIGestureRecognizer`, and tie its behavior to the `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` of your `UIViewController`.

---

**Edit :**

Here is a solution I built. You can implement your own transition conforming to the `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` delegate. This solution **works**, but has not been thoroughly tested.

You will get an **interactive** sliding transition to pop your ViewControllers. You can slide to right from anywhere in the view.

Known issue : if you start the pan and stop before half the width of the view, the transition is canceled (expected behavior). During this process, the views reset to their original frames. Their is a visual glitch during this animation.

The classes of the example are the following :

> UINavigationController > ViewController > SecondViewController

**CustomPopTransition.h** :

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface CustomPopTransition : NSObject <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>

@end
```

**CustomPopTransition.m** :

```
#import "CustomPopTransition.h"
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation CustomPopTransition

- (NSTimeInterval)transitionDuration:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {
    return 0.3;
}

- (void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext {

    SecondViewController *fromViewController = (SecondViewController*)[transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
    ViewController *toViewController = (ViewController*)[transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];

    UIView *containerView = [transitionContext containerView];
    [containerView addSubview:toViewController.view];
    [containerView bringSubviewToFront:fromViewController.view];

    // Setup the initial view states
    toViewController.view.frame = [transitionContext finalFrameForViewController:toViewController];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{

        fromViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(toViewController.view.frame.size.width, fromViewController.view.frame.origin.y, fromViewController.view.frame.size.width, fromViewController.view.frame.size.height);

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        // Declare that we've finished
        [transitionContext completeTransition:!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled];
    }];

}

@end
```

**SecondViewController.h** :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@end
```

**SecondViewController.m** :

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CustomPopTransition.h"

@interface SecondViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition *interactivePopTransition;

@end

@implementation SecondViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.navigationController.delegate = self;

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *popRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handlePopRecognizer:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:popRecognizer];
}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];

    // Stop being the navigation controller's delegate
    if (self.navigationController.delegate == self) {
        self.navigationController.delegate = nil;
    }
}

- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController animationControllerForOperation:(UINavigationControllerOperation)operation fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromVC toViewController:(UIViewController *)toVC {

    // Check if we're transitioning from this view controller to a DSLSecondViewController
    if (fromVC == self && [toVC isKindOfClass:[ViewController class]]) {
        return [[CustomPopTransition alloc] init];
    }
    else {
        return nil;
    }
}

- (id<UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning>)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController interactionControllerForAnimationController:(id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationController {

    // Check if this is for our custom transition
    if ([animationController isKindOfClass:[CustomPopTransition class]]) {
        return self.interactivePopTransition;
    }
    else {
        return nil;
    }
}

- (void)handlePopRecognizer:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {

    // Calculate how far the user has dragged across the view
    CGFloat progress = [recognizer translationInView:self.view].x / (self.view.bounds.size.width * 1.0);
    progress = MIN(1.0, MAX(0.0, progress));

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        NSLog(@"began");
        // Create a interactive transition and pop the view controller
        self.interactivePopTransition = [[UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition alloc] init];
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
    else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        NSLog(@"changed");
        // Update the interactive transition's progress
        [self.interactivePopTransition updateInteractiveTransition:progress];
    }
    else if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded || recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled) {
        NSLog(@"ended/cancelled");
        // Finish or cancel the interactive transition
        if (progress > 0.5) {
            [self.interactivePopTransition finishInteractiveTransition];
        }
        else {
            [self.interactivePopTransition cancelInteractiveTransition];
        }

        self.interactivePopTransition = nil;
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: any idea How can i do that?

Comment: @chetu : Nope, sorry.. I'll let you know if I find a way, but your best option is to try by yourself..

Comment: https://github.com/vinqon/MultiLayerNavigation/blob/master/Src/MLNavigationController.m

this will work but limitation is, when we use a slide view controller it's don't work. Ex- pop(back) not working.

@dipang

Comment: Thanks a lot, chetu. brilliant solution! (MultiLayerNavigation)

Comment: Works perfect on 9.0. Thank you. I don't see the visual glitch you mentioned either.

Comment: @Alec : it may have been resolved in iOS 8 / 9, since this post is almost 2 years old :) Glad it helped !

Comment: Do you think you could update this to a swift solution? :)

Comment: @Tometoyou: sorry, I haven't played around with Swift much yet.. But if you give it a go, feel free to edit the post and add the Swift version :)

Comment: works great! I would recommend: instead of checking
`if (fromVC == self && [toVC isKindOfClass:[ViewController class]])`
I checked
`if (fromVC == self && operation == UINavigationControllerOperationPop && self.isSwiping == YES)`
for a more general solution I can use everywhere. The bool isSwiping is for the back-button so that clicking the backbutton will use a default animation. isSwiping will be set within `handlePopRecognizer`. thx a lot!

Comment: Here is more elegant solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35388985/57487724#57487724

Answer (score 7):

Create a pan gesture recogniser and move the interactive pop gesture recogniser's targets across.

Add your recogniser to the pushed view controller's viewDidLoad and voila!

```swift
let popGestureRecognizer = self.navigationController!.interactivePopGestureRecognizer!
if let targets = popGestureRecognizer.value(forKey: "targets") as? NSMutableArray {
  let gestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer()
  gestureRecognizer.setValue(targets, forKey: "targets")
  self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
}
```

Comment: I laughed when this worked. That's brilliant. Great answer.

Comment: Thanks, here is a detailed solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/57487724/1745000

Answer (score 5):

Here's a Swift version of Spynet's answer, with a few modifications. Firstly, I've defined a linear curve for the `UIView` animation. Secondly, I've added a semi-transparent black background to the view underneath for a better effect. Thirdly, I've subclassed a `UINavigationController`. This allows the transition to be applied to any "Pop" transition within the UINavigationController. Here's the code:

**CustomPopTransition.swift**

```
import UIKit

class CustomPopTransition: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return 0.3
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
        guard let fromViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.from),
            let toViewController = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey.to)
            else {
                return
        }

        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView
        containerView.insertSubview(toViewController.view, belowSubview: fromViewController.view)

        // Setup the initial view states
        toViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: -100, y: toViewController.view.frame.origin.y, width: fromViewController.view.frame.size.width, height: fromViewController.view.frame.size.height)

        let dimmingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width: toViewController.view.frame.width, height: toViewController.view.frame.height))
        dimmingView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        dimmingView.alpha = 0.5

        toViewController.view.addSubview(dimmingView)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext),
                       delay: 0,
                       options: UIView.AnimationOptions.curveLinear,
                       animations: {
                        dimmingView.alpha = 0
                        toViewController.view.frame = transitionContext.finalFrame(for: toViewController)
                        fromViewController.view.frame = CGRect(x: toViewController.view.frame.size.width, y: fromViewController.view.frame.origin.y, width: fromViewController.view.frame.size.width, height: fromViewController.view.frame.size.height)
        },
                       completion: { finished in
                        dimmingView.removeFromSuperview()
                        transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
        }
        )
    }
}
```

**PoppingNavigationController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class PoppingNavigationController : UINavigationController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    var interactivePopTransition: UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.delegate = self
    }

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        addPanGesture(viewController: viewController)
    }

    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationController.Operation, from fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        if (operation == .pop) {
            return CustomPopTransition()
        }
        else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, interactionControllerForAnimationController animationController: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning) -> UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning? {
        if animationController.isKind(of: CustomPopTransition.self) {
            return interactivePopTransition
        }
        else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    func addPanGesture(viewController: UIViewController) {
        let popRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePanRecognizer(recognizer:)))
        viewController.view.addGestureRecognizer(popRecognizer)
    }

    @objc
    func handlePanRecognizer(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        // Calculate how far the user has dragged across the view
        var progress = recognizer.translation(in: self.view).x / self.view.bounds.size.width
        progress = min(1, max(0, progress))
        if (recognizer.state == .began) {
            // Create a interactive transition and pop the view controller
            self.interactivePopTransition = UIPercentDrivenInteractiveTransition()
            self.popViewController(animated: true)
        }
        else if (recognizer.state == .changed) {
            // Update the interactive transition's progress
            interactivePopTransition.update(progress)
        }
        else if (recognizer.state == .ended || recognizer.state == .cancelled) {
            // Finish or cancel the interactive transition
            if (progress > 0.5) {
                interactivePopTransition.finish()
            }
            else {
                interactivePopTransition.cancel()
            }
            interactivePopTransition = nil
        }
    }
}
```

Example of the result:
[image]

Comment: @Spynet No problem! I just updated the CustomPopTransition.swift code because I had noticed a bug with the other code on here to do with what happens when you drag and then release multiple times before you commit to swiping back...

Comment: Good job keep-it up

Answer (score 2):

Subclassing the `UINavigationController` you can add a `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` to trigger the pop action:

**.h file:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CNavigationController : UINavigationController

@end
```

**.m file:**

```
#import "CNavigationController.h"

@interface CNavigationController ()<UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, retain) UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGesture;

@end

@implementation CNavigationController

#pragma mark - View cycles

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    __weak CNavigationController *weakSelf = self;
    self.delegate = weakSelf;

    self.swipeGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gestureFired:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.swipeGesture]; }

#pragma mark - gesture method

-(void)gestureFired:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    if (gesture.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)
    {
        [self popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    } }

#pragma mark - UINavigation Controller delegate

- (void)pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    self.swipeGesture.enabled = NO;
    [super pushViewController:viewController animated:animated]; }

#pragma mark UINavigationControllerDelegate

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
       didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                    animated:(BOOL)animate {
    self.swipeGesture.enabled = YES; }

@end
```

Comment: Paste your code in your answer. If your link dies, your answer is useless.

Comment: This solution uses a swipe, so you don't get control over the transition. It won't be interactive, whereas Apple's implementation is.

Comment: @rdurand i need to support ios6 device that's y i did like that

Comment: That's an acceptable solution in this case. I added a working iOS7+ solution in my answer.

Comment: @rdurand is it okay now

Answer (score 2):

There really is no need to roll your own solution for this, sub-classing `UINavigationController` and referencing the built-in gesture works just fine as explained [here](http://liudanyun.com/blog/?p=452).

The same solution in Swift:

```
public final class MyNavigationController: UINavigationController {

  public override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.fullScreenPanGestureRecognizer)
  }

  private lazy var fullScreenPanGestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer = {
    let gestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer()

    if let cachedInteractionController = self.value(forKey: "_cachedInteractionController") as? NSObject {
      let string = "handleNavigationTransition:"
      let selector = Selector(string)
      if cachedInteractionController.responds(to: selector) {
        gestureRecognizer.addTarget(cachedInteractionController, action: selector)
      }
    }

    return gestureRecognizer
  }()
}
```

If you do this, also implement the following `UINavigationControllerDelegate` function to avoid strange behaviour at the root view controller:

```
public func navigationController(_: UINavigationController,
                                 didShow _: UIViewController, animated _: Bool) {
  self.fullScreenPanGestureRecognizer.isEnabled = self.viewControllers.count > 1
}
```

Comment: not bad! but animation is working a bit weird. seems like view controller which you're dragging going to final position without animation. for example in instagram or telegram iOS app's it's more smoothie, starting to animate to final position from ~20-30pt and also checking if the direction of swipe changed then smoothly animating view to initial position. + what i also don't like - seems like your code is a bit hacky; looks like you are calling private methods which can be removed by apple. but i voted for it :)

Comment: Did you implement the second part of the answer? I had to do that to avoid any strange behaviour with the animation. I hear you on the private methods but I've submitted an app to the store with this code and it worked just fine. Also check the link in the answer for the original description of this solution (it's not my idea :))

Comment: Ah I see the link is no longer valid for the source of the solution.

Comment: thanks anyway!) this solution is best from the others, also short and universal cuz working with navigation controller not with the UIViewController.