# How to interactive pop (swipe to go back) anywhere in a UITableViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

Trying to make a UITableViewController work like the Reddit app comment section.

Basically, anywhere on the table view, swiping vertically scrolls the table, and swiping right triggers the navigation controller's interactively pop, exactly like the system default's "swipe to go back" gesture from screen edge.

How is that done? Thank you in advance!

Edit: I have it working in a non-scrollable view. How about a UITableView?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Navigation pop view when swipe right like Instagram iPhone app.How i achieve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22244688/navigation-pop-view-when-swipe-right-like-instagram-iphone-app-how-i-achieve-thi)

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of that question. I have gotten this to work in a non-scrollable view. How do I get it to work in a scrollable view like UITableView though?

Comment: Maybe you can look at an implementation through the editing style and functions that come with a UITableView (`canEditRowAtIndexPath` and `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`)