# how to change ios7 interactivePopGestureRecognizer scope?

Tags: ios7, interactivepopgesture

as you know, ios7 swipe left-to-right pop effect is so cool, but only while user touch very close to screen's boundary, this gesture can be triggered, any one has idea to enlarge the scope?

Comment: See my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23980207/1990236